# How to merge 2 tables with different structures into 1 table using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables here that I need to merge.

table1
pk1
appt_id
other_fields_here

table2
pk2
appt_id
other_fields_here (mostly different name but there are some with the same name from table1)

The table is going to be merge using appt_id as the matching key. Any records on that doesn't have a match gets carried over to the new table.

Please see the example below to give a better idea on what I want to accomplish.

Thanks a lot.

---

**example: There are only 2 records in each table. The new table will have 3 records after the merge.**

**scenario1**: matching appt_id (This will create a single record on the new table.)

```
table1: pk1=1 | appt_id=1 | field1=test1

table2: pk2=1 | appy_id=1 | field2=test1

new pk = autoincrement | appt=1 | field1=test1 | field2=test1
```

---

**scenario2**: appt_id has no matching records (This will create 2 new records in the new table)

```
table1: pk1=293454 | appt_id=34535 | field1=test34535

table2: pk2=735353 | appt_id=88888 | field2=test88888

new pk = autoincrement | appt=34535 | field1=test34535 | field2=null

new pk = autoincrement | appt=88888 | field1=null | field2=test88888
```

Comment: check column name text in scenario1. i thing you mismach the column name in second table it should be appt_id not appy_id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use join and UNION both. Check this [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6706b5/18/0)

```
SELECT t.appt_id,t.field1,t2.field2 FROM table1 t LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t.appt_id = t2.appt_id
UNION
SELECT t2.appt_id,t.field1,t2.field2 FROM table2 t2 LEFT JOIN table1 t ON t.appt_id = t2.appt_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This thing is called `FULL OUTER JOIN`

Unfortunately MySQL does not support this kind of joins.

You can achieve emulate it's result with the following query:

```
SELECT
  * -- list required fields here!
FROM
  table1 T1
  LEFT JOIN table2 T2
    ON T1.appt_id

UNION

SELECT
  * -- list required fields here!
FROM
  table1 T1
  RIGHT JOIN table2 T2
    ON T1.appt_id
```

Answer (score 0):

`insert into new_table(appt_id, field) select appt_id, field1 from table1 union select appt_id, field2 from table2;`

union will get only unique records from both tables. If you need all records use `union all`.
I assume field1 and field2 has the same value when appt_id is the same.